# How do I copy a world state in Dragon Age Keep

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't seem to find an easy way to save a new copy of a world state in Dragon Age Keep.  I want to start with one base state and explore several variations, and I don't want to reenter everything many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy from "playthrough states" (menu -> world states -> playthrough states).

Those are taken from your actual playthrough so basically you need to make only one world state, import it in inquisition and then you can copy it to a new editable slot (as explained above).